# Custom JQUERY Not Loading On Paginated Pages (Except First Page)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am running the following jQuery that affects elements on a page view.
 My function's as below:

```
  $("#clname").on("change", function() {
    var value = $(this).val();

    $("table tr").each(function(index) {
      if (index !== 0) {

        $row = $(this);

        var id = $row.find("td:eq(0)").text();

        if (id.indexOf(value) !== 0) {
            $row.hide();
        }
        else {
            $row.show();
        }
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: Show us the code for paginated page and how are you loading custom jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to reuse the code in your pagination callback.

Edit: If you use ajax just add the code in the success function:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/pagination',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            //ADD your code here
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, err) {
            console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
        }
    });
}
```

If you are not using Ajax just add the code on a on click function for the pagination.

```
 $('body')on('click', '.pagination>a', function(event) {
  $("#clname").on("change", function() {
  var value = $(this).val();

  $("table tr").each(function(index) {
   if (index !== 0) {

    $row = $(this);

    var id = $row.find("td:eq(0)").text();

    if (id.indexOf(value) !== 0) {
        $row.hide();
    }
    else {
        $row.show();
    }
  }
   });
  });
  });
```

Comment: Dear Dan Neciu How to reuse the code in pagination call back please give an example